# How to run a PhoneGap application on android emulator?

Tags: android, cordova

I am  unable to run the phoneGap application on the android emulator,
I am following step by step process of 
- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

But  I am getting the error

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Config cannot be resolved   PhoneGapdemo.java   /PhoneGapdemo/src/com/appovative/testpgap   line 32 Java Problem
DroidGap cannot be resolved to a type   PhoneGapdemo.java   /PhoneGapdemo/src/com/appovative/testpgap   line 25 Java Problem
DroidGap cannot be resolved to a type   PhoneGapdemo.java   /PhoneGapdemo/src/com/appovative/testpgap   line 30 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved    PhoneGapdemo.java   /PhoneGapdemo/src/com/appovative/testpgap   line 23 Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type PhoneGapdemo must override or implement a supertype method  PhoneGapdemo.java   /PhoneGapdemo/src/com/appovative/testpgap   line 28 Java Problem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a special reason why you're using the old 2.9 version?

Anyway I think that your problem is that there's been a change in phonegap 2.9.1 and the api is no more in a jar but in a separate project named cordova-lib. When you import the project in eclipse, you should see two projects instead of one. Adding the two projects should solve your problem.